# html table border not showing on web

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am having trouble getting a border on a table. Here is the html for the table it shows having a border in Dreamweaver but not on the live webpage. I also have other tables on the page and do not want them to have the borders just this one.

```html
<table style="width: 100%;" border="1" bordercolor="#000000">
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2" align="center" valign="middle">Please comeplete form</td>
          </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="50%">Event Name:</td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Date (YYYY-MM-DD):</td>
          <td>
            <textarea name="date" id="date"></textarea></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Link to page:</td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" name="link" id="link"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Status:</td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" name="status" id="status"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2" align="center" valign="middle"><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit"></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
```

Comment: instead of using deprecated attributes like `bordercolor`, implement the border in css. `table {border: 1px solid #000}`

Comment: Why not just use css instead of the table border and border color?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add CSS to bring it up to standard

Something like:

```
table.mytable{
   border: 1px solid #000000;
}
```

and then add a `class="mytable"` attribute to your table

Comment: How can i make td and th specific to the table too? <style type="text/css">
table.addform{
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>

Comment: Use `table.mytable th` and  `table.mytable td`

Answer (score 0):

You can initially style it like:

```
table,td,th {
  border-collapse:collapse;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}
```

And in this way further you can add this as a class.